# Connecting two networks

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, routing

I want to interconnect two networks.

Each of the networks should connect to the other by a PC running Ubuntu.

So, I have three networks:
NW1: 192.168.1.x  NW2: 192.168.2.x and MgmtNW: 192.168.3.x that are connected as follows:

`NW1--Ubuntu1---MgmtNW---Ubuntu2--NW2`

Right now with the setup I have I able to "see" a computer in NW2 from the router "Ubuntu1" but surprisingly I cannot see another computer in NW1 from the router Ubuntu2. I cannot see the client in NW2 from the client in NW1.

My setup is as follows:

Each Ubuntu server has a network interface configured in the MgmtNW (192.168.3.x) and another configured in NW1 and NW2 respectively.

Ubuntu1 has interfaces setup as follows:
192.168.1.10
192.168.3.10

Ubuntu2 has interfaces setup as follows:
192.168.2.20
192.168.2.20

I have set `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in both routers.

Besides I have also configured the following routes:

In Ubuntu1:

```
route add -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.3.20 #20 is the Ubuntu2 interface into mgmt NW
```

In Ubuntu2:

```
route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.3.10 #10 is the Ubuntu1 interface into mgmt NW
```

The default GW for machines in 192.168.1.x is 192.168.1.10 (Ubuntu1) and for machines in 192.168.2.x is 192.168.2.20 (ubuntu2).

What am I missing?  Do I have to add iptables rules?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you have to use NAT and also allow forwarding and input on both routers.

Comment: You certainly don't have to use NAT in this scenario, but you probably want to check iptables to see that the default FORWARD policy is set to ACCEPT, and that there are no rules blocking your traffic. The symptoms you describe seem most likely to be caused by Ubuntu2 not really having a route to 192.168.1.x, or blocking traffic to that network. That's where I'd look first.

Comment: Thanks, no need to add any rule to iptables was needed in the end.
It had a toke mispelled in sysctl.conf... :( that was all in the end, and the machine was not forwarding packets.

Answer (score 1):

By default you don't need to setup firewall rules - every packet is accepted.

Please, avoid to use utils from net-tools collection (`route` in your example) with modern linux distributions - most of them are [obsolete](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/net-tools) now by [iproute2 utils](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2). There is `ip route` tool for your needs, view the man pages: `man ip-route`.

If `ip address` command shows that ip's are right, `ip route` shows that you have routes to all subnets (local subnets too, with right mask) and ip forwarding is enabled - everything must work as well.

You can use `tcpdump` to find interface where you're loosing packets. By the way, windows machines may not answer ping request by default.

Comment: One needs to also make sure that the client machines in NW1 and NW2 have correct routes to the other network. It might be that those machines have some other default gateway defined than the MGMT network one.

Comment: Yes, it is good idea to check client machine's settings - ip's, subnet masks and gateway addresss.

Comment: Thanks for the iproute2 utils advice Alex.
Besides finding the mispelled token at sysctl.conf I changed the route commands to what you posted.